# getting intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 in Javascript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

When you enter Javascript in an HTML file, you get intellisense code completion based on the Javascript files you have linked into the head of your HTML file.

I know there is a way to add comments with JS filenames into the top of a Javascript file, so that VS2010 will reference these files as you type code into the rest of the file below.

How does one do that?  Or can you point me to a reference that describes the syntax?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/// <reference path="ScriptFile1.js" />
```

See the References Directives section - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx